# Background service kill my app when start application

Tags: java, android, crash, android-8.0-oreo

Want to run a service in back ground when SMS or call received then background service call the flash on and off.  Application works on marshmallow and low version. But not work on Oreo 8.0 and Pie 9.0. Due to Background service application crash after 10 second when application open.

```
Android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() 
    did not then call Service.startForeground()
```

How we fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call "Service.startForeground()" within few seconds after called "startForegroundService()" or the Service will be killed by Android.

Changes from Android 8: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes